# $f(x)$ has 3 distinct solutions on $[a,b]$ and $f(x)$ has a continuous second derivative on $[a,b]$, then $f''(x)+2f(x)$ has solutions on $[a,b]$

Tags: mean-value-theorem

Prove if $f(x)$  has 3 distinct solutions on $[a,b]$ and $f(x)$ has a continuous second derivative on $[a,b]$, then $f''(x)+2f(x)$ has solutions on $[a,b]$.

I'm stuck for ideas on this problem. Where can I start?
Is it possible to generalize with random c (instead of 2)?

Comment: What do you mean by f(x) has a solution? f(x)=0?

Comment: That's right $f(x) = 0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We solve for the general case $f''(x) +c\cdot f(x)$.

---

### If $c >0$:

(for example, $c = 2$ as in the question)

In this case, the question is *wrong*, that is: $f''(x)+2f(x)$ may have *no* solution. Here is a **counter-example**:

Let us define
$$f(x) := \sin(\sqrt{c} \cdot x) -1$$
The function $f(x)$ has $3$ solutions $x \in \left\{ \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{c}}, \frac{5\pi}{2\sqrt{c}}, \frac{9\pi}{2\sqrt{c}}  \right\}$ over the interval $\left[\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{c}},\frac{9\pi}{2\sqrt{c}}  \right]$.

However,
$$f''(x) + c\cdot f(x) = \underbrace{-c\sin(\sqrt{c} \cdot x)+c\sin(\sqrt{c} \cdot x)}_{=0}- c \ne 0  \hspace{1cm} \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

---

### If $c \le 0$:

(for example, $c = -2$)

In this case, the question is correct. Here is the proof:

Denote $g(x):=e^{ \sqrt{|c|}\cdot   x}\cdot f(x)$ .

The function $g(x)$ has $3$ distinct solutions in $[a,b]$, then
$g'(x)$ has $2$ distinct solutions in $[a,b]$, we have
$$g'(x) =e^{\sqrt{|c|}\cdot   x}\cdot  \left(\sqrt{|c|}\cdot f(x)+f'(x) \right) $$

The function $\left(\sqrt{|c|}\cdot f(x)+f'(x)\right)$ must have $2$ distinct solutions in $[a,b]$.

Denote $h(x) = e^{\color{red}{-}\sqrt{|c|}\cdot   x}\cdot \left(\sqrt{c}\cdot f(x)+f'(x)\right)$, its derivative $h'(x)$ must have $1$ solution in $[a,b]$:

$$h'(x) =e^{- \sqrt{|c|}\cdot   x}\cdot  \left( -|c|\cdot  f(x)+f''(x) \right)=e^{- \sqrt{|c|}\cdot   x}\cdot  \left(\color{red}{ c\cdot  f(x)+f''(x)} \right) $$

The function $\left(c\cdot  f(x)+f''(x)\right)$ must have a solution in $[a,b]$.

Comment: I am having doubts about the application of the mean value theorem for a complex-valued function. For example, the function $f(t)=\cos t+(1+\sin t)i$ vanishes for $t=-\pi/2$ and $t=3\pi/2$ but its derivative $f'(t)=-\sin t+i\cos t $ never vanishes since $\sin^2 t+\cos^2 t=1$. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Why not? $1+\sin t=0$ both for $t=-\pi/2$ and $t=3\pi/2$.

Comment: @GReyes In fact, the question is not correct when $c >0$. I provide a counter-example for this case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Mark You're welcome!